# How to highlight element before clicking?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests using Selenium WebDriver. While tests run, I want to know which element is being interacted. This can be achieved by highlighting that element before performing any action on that element. Is there any Selenium WebDriver api (for Ruby) available to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to inject JS to achieve that. (which may cause unknown issues?)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/marciomazza/3086536

Comment: Do you want to check if the element is present on the page,before clicking?

Comment: If your elements are all TEXT and you are working on windows env I can show you a way of achieving this by hitting CTRL+F and then letting your browser highlight it for you. I've used it successfully in the past but I'm not sure if it is fir for your purpose..Let me know

Comment: Sorry everybody, I didn't receive notification emails for you comment or I might have missed them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you @user1177636! The documentation you pointed out helped. I could highlight element. I'm pasting answer so that it might help others who want to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I could find solution for this. Following is the way, using javascript, we can highlight element:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "color: yellow; border: 2px solid yell>
```

And following is to remove highlight from it:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", height, "")
```